# sequence to perform filtering? which filter first?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

Is there a generally accepted rule as to which order to perform filtering in?

for example if I have a low pass filter a notch and a high pass filter, which sequence would it be best to perform these in? or does it not make any difference at all?

cheers, Graham.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for this kind of theoretical non-programming question. That said, If your filters are linear and time invariant (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTI_system_theory)), then the order of the filters does not matter, at least in theory. In practice, there may be cases where numerical stability is affected by the filtering order, but that's very much dependant on your specific filter implementation.